# Flattening data in SQL server by joining multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, join, parent-child, multiple-tables

I want to flatten parent-child tables for data analysis purposes. 
I have Service order table tssoc210 as

```
orno|acln
1   |10 
1   |20
2   |20
.
.
```

it's activities(labour,material,other) are maintained in 3 other tables as 
tssoc220 (for labour)

```
orno|acln|lino|invn|eqan|asto
1   |10  |A   |600 |2   |120
1   |10  |B   |607 |1   |100
.
.
```

tssoc230 (for materials)

```
orno|acln|lino|invn|eqan|asto
1   |10  |L1  |700 |1   |110
1   |10  |L2  |704 |3   |200
1   |10  |L3  |407 |4   |100
1   |20  |L1  |708 |1   |100  
2   |20  |L1  |790 |1   |200
.
.
```

tssoc240(for other)

```
orno|acln|lino|invn|eqan|asto
1   |10  |M1  |400 |2   |500
2   |20  |M1  |490 |1   |100
.
.
```

I want to join these tables as

```
orno|acln|l_lino|l_invn|l_eqan|l_asto|m_lino|m_invn|m_eqan|m_asto|o_lino|o_invn|o_eqan|o_asto
1   |10  |A     |600   |2     |120   |NULL  |NULL  |NULL  |NULL  |NULL  |NULL  |NULL  |NULL
1   |10  |B     |607   |1     |100   |NULL  |NULL  |NULL  |NULL  |NULL  |NULL  |NULL  |NULL
1   |10  | NULL |NULL  |NULL  |NULL  |L1    |700   |1     |110   |NULL  |NULL  |NULL  |NULL
1   |10  | NULL |NULL  |NULL  |NULL  |L2    |704   |3     |200   |NULL  |NULL  |NULL  |NULL
1   |10  | NULL |NULL  |NULL  |NULL  |L3    |407   |4     |100   |NULL  |NULL  |NULL  |NULL
1   |10  | NULL |NULL  |NULL  |NULL  |NULL  |NULL  |NULL  |NULL  |M1    |400   |2     |500
1   |20  | NULL |NULL  |NULL  |NULL  |L1    |708   |1     |100   |NULL  |NULL  |NULL  |NULL
2   |20  | NULL |NULL  |NULL  |NULL  |L1    |790   |1     |200   |NULL  |NULL  |NULL  |NULL
2   |20  | NULL |NULL  |NULL  |NULL  |NULL  |NULL  |NULL  |NULL  |M1    |490   |1     |100
.
.
```

If I left join tssoc220,tssoc230, tssoc240 with tssoc210(tssoc210 as a left table), it duplicates the row.

```
left join tssoc220 ON  tssoc210.orno = tssoc220.orno and tssoc210.acln = tssoc220.acln
left join tssoc230 ON  tssoc210.orno = tssoc230.orno and tssoc210.acln = tssoc230.acln 
left join tssoc240 ON  tssoc210.orno = tssoc240.orno and tssoc210.acln = tssoc240.acln
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If you join those four tables on orno an acln, for orno=1, acln=10, you'll get 1 x 2 x 3 x 1 = 6 records. Maybe you need to join on `eqan` as well. I can't really say. This is a question that requires knowledge of what the tables are modelling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to write 3 queries that join only 1 table and union them.

```
SELECT tssoc210.orno,tssoc210.acln,tssoc220.l_lino,tssoc220.l_invn,tssoc220.l_eqan,tssoc220.l_asto,NULL as m_lino,NULL as m_invn,NULL as m_eqan,NULL as m_asto,NULL as o_lino,NULL as o_invn,NULL as o_eqan,NULL as o_asto
FROM tssoc210 
left join tssoc220 ON  tssoc210.orno = tssoc220.orno and tssoc210.acln = tssoc220.acln
UNION ALL 
SELECT  tssoc210.orno,tssoc210.acln,NULL as l_lino,NULL as l_invn,NULL as l_eqan,NULL as l_asto,tssoc230.m_lino,tssoc230.m_invn,tssoc230.m_eqan,tssoc230.m_asto,NULL as o_lino,NULL as o_invn,NULL as o_eqan,NULL as o_asto
FROM tssoc210 
left join tssoc230 ON  tssoc210.orno = tssoc230.orno and tssoc210.acln = tssoc230.acln 
UNION ALL 
SELECT  tssoc210.orno,tssoc210.acln,NULL as l_lino,NULL as l_invn,NULL as l_eqan,NULL as l_asto,,NULL as m_lino,NULL as m_invn,NULL as m_eqan,NULL as m_asto,tssoc240.o_lino,tssoc240.o_invn,tssoc240.o_eqan,tssoc240.o_asto
FROM tssoc210 
left join tssoc240 ON  tssoc210.orno = tssoc240.orno and tssoc210.acln = tssoc240.acln
```